# Wordpress get category main name

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So if I'm on a subcategory page...how can I get the name of the main category?
So let's say I'm on site.com **/my-category/my-subcategory/** so how can I get "my-category" ? I don't want to parse the url :) cuz' I think wordpress has a built in function or smth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by using `get_the_category())` and `->category_parent`

Comment: Remember to do this multiple times if needed, if you want the top category and your nested goes beyond two levels. The closest related function is probably [`get_category_parents`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents).